# Redux Form FieldArray parse and format

Tags: redux-form

When using a `FieldArray` the data are parsed and stored in Redux as an array of objects. In my case:

```
[
   {
       email: "something@domain.ext"
   },
   {
       email: "another@domain.ext"
   }
]
```

I would like to use the `parse` and `format` property to store in redux an array of strings instead of objects like so:

```
[
     'something@domain.ext',
     'another@domain.ext'
]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out i just needed to set `onClick={() => fields.push()}` on the Add email button. That would not create an object but just an array of plain strings.